# Spring bean creation

Tags: spring

Is it possible to create to bean with same id with same class with different property in spring ? Like:

```
 <bean id ="a" class= "com.tofek.A"
   <property message = "khan"/>
</bean> 

<bean id = "a" class = "com.tofek.A"
  <property message="tofek"/>
</bean>
```

As per my understanding it will create, but while fetching the bean using getBean() method it will give exception like `NoBeanDefinitionFoundException`.

Please correct my understanding if I'm wrong?

Comment: Did you try it? You need to make your questions more specific and show some evidence that you have researched the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your spring context is loaded sucessfully.

Answering your question. You can have two identical bean definitions in two different sprintContext configurations.

The bean from second context will override bean created by first one. 
For example :

context1.xml

```
<bean id="bean1" class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean"/>
```

context2.xml

```
<bean id="bean1" class="org.springframework.beans.TestBean"/>
```

then, the bean from context2.xml will override bean created by contex1.xml. 
It of course depends on order of creating spring contexts. The laters overrides the ones made before.

You can use getBean() to fetch bean by type or name. In this case, both bean have same id's and types, the spring wouldn't know which one you want to fetch.